# how to decrypt a http request captured during packet capture

Tags: http, fiddler, wireshark, packet-capture

Hi Guys Im currently capturing some traffic from an android application, but the requests it is sending out to server seems encrypted. Would you guys know how to decrypt such requests? Or is that impossible to do?

platform=android&version=1.0.31&lang=en&requestId=44&time=1485552535566&batch=%5b%7b%22id%22%3a177205%2c%22time%22%3a1485552512601%2c%22name%22%3a%22collectResource%22%2c%22params%22%3a%5b155%5d%2c%22hash%22%3a1948904473%7d%5d&sessionId=674937_bc59a16eae9e1559b2e60ae068baf4e7

Comment: This is not encrypted, look into decoding. Search for online tools like with 'decode url string'.

Answer (score 1):

That's not encrypted, it's encoded.  Do a search for "online url decode".  In your example you will get:

platform=android&version=1.0.31&lang=en&requestId=44&time=1485552535566&batch=[{"id":177205,"time":1485552512601,"name":"collectResource","params":[155],"hash":1948904473}]&sessionId=674937_bc59a16eae9e1559b2e60ae068baf4e7

Answer (score 1):

The %xx are url encoded hex values.  For example %22 is the hex version of the double quote character.  I think that if you use javascript or other tool to decode the url encoding or manually change all % strings to the equivalent characters, you will see that the message is really just url encoded plain text.